# c# fastest way to get a subset of integer list

Tags: c#, list, math, mathematical-optimization

i get 5 list and i need subset of all.

- I) 200.000 integer values
- II)  30.000 integer values
- III)  10.000 integer values
- IV)     200 integer values

in math terms A **n** B **n** C **n** D. I need to do this 1.000 concurrent users.

- what is the **fastest way** to do this with c# ?
- how many **concurrent** operations can i do with one 2 mhz CPU ? 2 billion cycle speed

Comment: With **one** CPU, you can only perform **one** *concurrent* operation.

Comment: @Nolonar what about hyperthreading?  Also note CPUs are very smart about actually parallelizing work in a pipeline.  It can actually be really hard to determine the degree of concurrency, depending on the definition you're using.  It simply parallelizes tasks in a manor such that can only ever be observed to be sequential externally.

Comment: Please clarify: 2MHz or 2GHz? Also, in multi-core CPU you can set a concurrency (refer to Task Parallel Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Comment: @Servy If I'm not mistaken, hyperthreading just pushes a second thread to the pipeline. The two threads run slightly deferred, but not *concurrently*.

Comment: @Nolonar Again, it depends somewhat on your definition of concurrent.  The CPU can be fetching the parameters for one operation from memory while *concurrently* adding two values together as another operation.  The concurrency is never observable externally, but it exists.  With hyperthreading you then get to the point where the concurrency can even be observed externally.  I won't assert that I'm an expert on the subject, I'm merely saying "concurrent" has a fuzzy definition that needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Servy You're right. I simply assumed the CPU wouldn't support all the fanciness of modern processors, given the fact that it's supposed to be clocked at only 2 MHz. (I'm not saying it's an old CPU though, only that at such a low clock, I don't think it'll sport hyperthreading or other fancy features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way of dealing with finding an intersection of multiple sets is language-agnostic: create a `HashSet<int>`, initialize it with the data from the shortest list, and then sequentially call [`IntersectWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) on the remaining lists. You need to start with the shortest list, because the complexity of the operation is `O(n+m)`, where `n` is the number of items in the `HashSet<int>`, and `m` is the number of items in the other list. Since `IntersectWith` will be called four times, and the complexity of setting up the initial `HashSet<int>` is `O(n)`, the overall complexity will be

```
O( n + n+m1 + n+m2 + n+m3 + n+m4)
// ^    ^      ^      ^      ^
// |    |      |      |      |
// |   Intersecting with lists 2..5
// |
// Setting up the initial HashSet<int>
```

Since the total is `O(5*n+m1+m2+m3+m4)`, the best approach is to pick the shortest list for making your initial set.